# convert images to video with differing time ranges

Tags: image, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have images coming in at random times labeled with their epoch time they were taken.  I want to create a video that shows their real time creation in order.  FFMPEG (far as I can tell) only allows you to set the framerate.

For now I'm looking at creating a video file per image that is as long as the gap between the current image and the next image's timestamp, then concatenating all videos together after.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can convert every image to video and after join all the videos.

1st: Convert image to video when time is the gap between your current image and the next.

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -f image2 -i your_image1.jpg -acodec pcm_s16le -t time_between_images -s width_x_height -y your_image1_to_video.mpg
```

2nd: Join all your video parts recursively

```
cat your_image1_to_video.mpg your_image2_to_video.mpg > videojoin1.mpg

cat videojoin1.mpg your_image3_to_video.mpg > videojoin2.mpg

....
```